# get data depend on particular id using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i just create the simple cart app.in this i add products to the cart,from that i want to buy the one particular product.So i want to get and display product based on product id. In this, i had receiving the error.Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Inserting product to database:

```
<?php     
 Include('connect.php');

 $productId=$_POST['productId'];
 $productName=$_POST['productName'];
 $productPrice=$_POST['productPrice'];
 $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];

 $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (productId,productName,productPrice,quantity) 
 VALUES ('$productId','$productName','$productPrice','$quantity')") or   die(mysql_error());

 if($sql){ 

  header('Location:buy.php');
   } 
  else
  {
  echo"Failed to add cart !";

   }
   ?>
```

Adding products to cart:

```
<?php 
include('connect.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM buy";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$myArray = array(); 

echo "<table  style='width:50%;'>
<tr>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Product Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>

</tr>";

$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
 $myArray[$index] = $row;
 $index++;

 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['productName'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['productPrice'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";

echo "<td><a href='quantity.php'><button class='btn  btn-default col-md- offset-2' value='submit'>Buy Now</button></a></td>" ;
echo "<td><button class='btn  btn-danger' value='submit'>Buy Later</button>    </td>" ;
echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

choose product and display product based on id:

```
 <?php 
 include('connect.php');

 $productId=$_GET['productId'];


 $sql="SELECT productName, productPrice, quantity FROM products WHERE productId=" . $productId . "";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 $myArray = array(); 

 echo "<table  style='width:50%;'>
 <tr>
 <th>Product Name</th>
 <th>Product Price</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>

 </tr>";

$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
 $myArray[$index] = $row;
 $index++;

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['productName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['productPrice'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the error? Where/When exactly do you get it? Please remove from your question all of the code that is not required for the question and leave **only** the relevant parts (for example - if you get an error I'm sure the `echo "<tr>"` is **not** relevant.

Comment: i get undefined index productId and  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\cart\buy.php on line 65

Comment: Great. Did you read my comment?

Comment: Yes, But i dont know at which place was the error was, so i posted all code in here

Comment: No one will read all of your code. You can see in the error that you have a problem in line 65 on the file buy.php. You can start from there...

Comment: ok, You Help me with the code